# Is there any way to pull the changes made in console using ask-cli? I couldn't find a command to do so

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am newbie and I have developed an Alexa Skill. I have already cloned the skill in my computer, but recently I have added new language support to my skill using the console. Now I want to pull those changes to my local copy. Is there a command to do so? I couldn't find one. If there isn't a command, then how to do it?

I have already ran ask -help, but it doesn't have any such commands to pull changes, or maybe I missed something.

I used `ask diff` to see the differences.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late but In case it helps anyone out their, I agree with @Dana answer but a slight change is required here which seems to be missing in their official documentation and i.e. the order of providing the parameters. It works only one way round mentioned below.

**ask api get-skill --stage development -s {skill_id}**

If you try and provider skill-id before stage , you will be server with error : -

**Please input required parameter: skill-id.**

Answer (score 1):

Command are changed for ask-cli v2 :

```
ask smapi get-skill-manifest [--skill-id | -s <skill-id>]
                           [--stage | -g <stage>]
                           [--profile | -p <profile>]
                           [--debug]
```

Official documentation for all high level and low apis >> https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html#get-skill-manifest-subcommand

Answer (score 0):

How about the get-skill command? https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html#get-skill-subcommand

get-skill subcommand
Outputs the schema for the skill with the specified skill ID to the terminal. You can optionally redirect this output to a file using the > operator as seen below.

$ ask api get-skill -s {skill_id} --stage development > skill.json